# How is the Fitbit OAuth authorization remembered/saved in this code?

Tags: oauth, google-apps-script, google-sheets, fitbit

I found this code that syncs Fitbit data to a Google spreadsheet. I would like to adapt it a bit, but i am stuck trying to figure out how the authorization is saved. I think my confusion is a result of a lack of understanding how OAuth works.

Here is the code: https://github.com/qslabs/FitbitDailyData/blob/master/FitbitDailyData.gs

It lets you configure the keys, and then when you authorize the first time in a spreadsheet, it pops up an authorization window. The next time it doesn't need the authorization window. I understand it won't ask for authorization if it's already authorized, but how does it remember which account authorized it? I don't see it saving any access tokens anywhere. Is it just automatic somehow when using Google script OAuth library?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the "oAuthServiceName" is the key to differentiating different accounts. The authentication is stored by Google, but if you change that value, then it will require a new authorization.